# Can wmic get model info of path or physical names?

Tags: windows, powershell, wmic

Is it possible to do this powershell script in plane old wmic commands? I need to get disk model info based off a path or drive letter if possible but am having issues running powershell scripts.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | % {
  $disk = $_
  $partitions = "ASSOCIATORS OF " +
                "{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='$($disk.DeviceID)'} " +
                "WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition"
  Get-WmiObject -Query $partitions | % {
    $partition = $_
    $drives = "ASSOCIATORS OF " +
              "{Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='$($partition.DeviceID)'} " +
              "WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"
    Get-WmiObject -Query $drives | % {
      New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Disk        = $disk.DeviceID
        DiskSize    = $disk.Size
        DiskModel   = $disk.Model
        Partition   = $partition.Name
        RawSize     = $partition.Size
        DriveLetter = $_.DeviceID
        VolumeName  = $_.VolumeName
        Size        = $_.Size
        FreeSpace   = $_.FreeSpace
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Script was shared in this question:
[Combine `Get-Disk` info and `LogicalDisk` info in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088930/combine-get-disk-info-and-logicaldisk-info-in-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand:

1. [wmic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) is for making single, simple queries.
2. If you want to make more sophisticated queries (for example, the nested loops above), you're going to need some kind of "programming language".  Like C#, VBScript ... or Powershell.
3. Q: What exactly are the "problems" you've encountered trying to execute this script?

Here is sample output from your script:

```
d:\>powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File tmp.ps1

DiskSize    : 128034708480
RawSize     : 117894545408
FreeSpace   : 44036825088
Disk        : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
DriveLetter : C:
DiskModel   : SanDisk SD6SF1M128G
VolumeName  : OS_Install
Size        : 117894541312
Partition   : Disk #1, Partition #2

DiskSize    : 320070320640
RawSize     : 320070836224
FreeSpace   : 29038071808
Disk        : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2
DriveLetter : E:
DiskModel   : TOSHIBA External USB 3.0 USB Device
VolumeName  : TOSHIBA EXT
Size        : 320070832128
Partition   : Disk #2, Partition #0

DiskSize    : 1000202273280
RawSize     : 734673240064
FreeSpace   : 141853818880
Disk        : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
DriveLetter : D:
DiskModel   : HGST HTS721010A9E630
VolumeName  : Data
Size        : 734673235968
Partition   : Disk #0, Partition #0
```

PS:

See also [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Comment: The -ExecutionPolicy ByPass was just what I needed. Thanks for pointing that out. :)