# Get drive letters from physical disk number under WinPE

Tags: powershell, winpe

I have a WinPE iso copied to an USB stick. In the WinPE environment the user enters a physical disk number. I want to create a warning if this physical disk looks like the WinPE disk.

My solution is to check whether the folders on it corresponds to the WinPE disk content. To do this I need the drive letter in order to `Test-Path`.

It looks like this solution [Combine `Get-Disk` info and `LogicalDisk` info in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088930/combine-get-disk-info-and-logicaldisk-info-in-powershell).

But it does not work in WinPE environment: [Some WMI doesn't work in Windows PE](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e84d2bd0-baca-42bf-9eb7-40314495b80d/some-wmi-doesnt-work-in-windows-pe-even-with-wmi-and-other-components-installed?forum=ITCG).

How can I check the content of the selected physical disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got something better for you, in the registry it stores what drive letter it booted from.
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\PEBootRamdiskSourceDrive

**Edit** To clarify if the you booted WinPE from a flash drive and it got assigned D:, then the value of that entry would be D:

Comment: This works, however is not there a way to tell the physical disk number of the disk WinPE was booted from?

Comment: For WMI there's Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition, whenever I'm looking for a way to do a query in WMI try WMI code creator
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572