# How to determine if it is SAN or local disk storage type using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, disk, san

I am using the below cmdlet to find out if it is SAN or local disk storage type

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive
```

However it is not giving the desired result. What is the correct cmdlet to distinguish between SAN or local storage?

Comment: Look at the `Root` property of `Get-PsDrive -PSProvider 'Filesystem'` or at the DriveType of `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_logicaldisk` (LocalDisk=3,NetworkDisk=4) Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31088930/combine-get-disk-info-and-logicaldisk-info-in-powershell

Comment: Please suggest how can i retrieve it using `get-disk` cmdlet

Comment: I didn't suggest `Get-Disk`, but take a look at the properties which that cmdlet exposes with `Get-Disk | Format-List *`

Comment: With `Get-Disk | Format-List *` I am not getting anything related to `local` or `network`. The property that makes sense to me is `BusType: Fibre Channel (for SAN)` Can you suggest if it is correct property?

Comment: Well again, **I** didn't suggest Get-Disk. It depends on how your SAN is integrated, an iScsi-Disk could posssibly be seen as a local disk. But IMO this gets a bit off topic here and is probaply better asked in [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com).