# Defrag system hdd only if is mechanical disk

Tags: powershell, hard-drive, solid-state-drive

we needed some help. in practice we were looking for a method to start the defremmentation (defrag) of the primary disk (on windows "C:") only if it is a HDD and not an SSD
we read about the command in powershell but can't compile (mediaType)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell: How to combine the output of 2 commands to associate disk letter with disk MediaType?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68883482/powershell-how-to-combine-the-output-of-2-commands-to-associate-disk-letter-wit)

Comment: windows does automatic defragmentation when it needs doing. so ... why are you wanting to override the standard behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script should work for you:

```
#Get friendly name of the C drive
$name = (get-partition -DriveLetter C | get-disk).FriendlyName

#Use friendly name to determine drive type
$mediatype = (Get-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName $name).MediaType

#Defragment drive if drive type is HDD

if ($mediatype -eq "HDD")
    {
        Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter C
    }
```